# vb script : how to create a button that open direct to access form inside access database without opening microsoft access

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2015

i have create a form that get data from a table and now i want to create a application via vb(visual studio 2015) that have a button that open the form without opening the Microsoft access...

Comment: This is gibberish.  VBScript is not VB.Net. Forms have nothing to do with MS Access. Forms are not inside databases.  Consider rewriting it and reading [ask] very carefully

Comment: @Plutonix you can actually create forms using MS Access (an Access file can contain forms and reports, not just data tables).

Comment: @ryan robert - if you could take a few moments to rewrite your question with some more detail you may find you get a better response. As it stands it's very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without opening Access. But you can create a button that will open Access, and show the form within in, without the user needing to open Access himself. I did similar things using VBA a very (very) long time ago (using `GetObject` and `CreateObject` to create an Access instance).